# Knockout js how to find a checked radio button in a radio button list

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I'm having a list of contact details. User can select, add and remove those contact details.(Please see the fiddle [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/QmQy9/) ) whenever the user click an add button, a new contact model item will be add to the DOM.

```
var ContactModel = {

           ContactData : [
                               { 'ContactKey': 12323, 'Ref': 'Reference-Marsh', 'ContactName': 'Marsh Global' },
                               { 'ContactKey': 44234, 'Ref': 'Reference-AON', 'ContactName': 'AON Co' },
                               { 'ContactKey': 65343, 'Ref': 'Reference-Europ', 'ContactName': 'Europ Ltd' },
                               { 'ContactKey': 78555, 'Ref': 'Reference-ECB', 'ContactName': 'ECB Tradings' },
                               { 'ContactKey': 24242, 'Ref': 'Reference-Jersey', 'ContactName': 'New Jersey Inc' }
           ],

             Items: ko.observableArray(),

             MainContacts : ko.observable(),

             AddItem: function () {
                 ContactModel.Items.push(new Contact([]));
             },
             Remove: function (line) {
                 ContactModel.Items.remove(line);

             }
         }
```

please see the rest of the code in the fiddle

[image]

when the user click a radio button, that selected radio button line data considered as main contact.I have to save all of the line items data. this is because when the user revisited the page,I'll bring all the line item with selected main contact.

when the user change the select list, the selected item object having the properties of ContactKey,Ref and ContactName according to that the other observable are updated.

but if the radio button is selected only the main contact will be updated. I've achieved that using pure jquery. but the value radio button value binding bit confusing for me. can any one help me to sort that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood your intentions right, my modifications to the fiddle shall present you a solution, basically:

- I gave names to the radio buttons so that they are exclusive.
- I moved logic from the view to the `ischecked` observable that is now a computed.
- I changed the binding logic for the main contact.
- Some small tweeks that can be seen in the fiddle.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QmQy9/4/

If theres something different from what you intended, just let me know.

Regards.

Comment: thank you for your help. i was struggling a bit to finish that. it worked charm. there is a question if i want to show the already selected contact while user viewing the page. when i pass a a parameter  ContactModel.Items.push(ContactModel.ContactData[1]) it throwing a undefined error. can you please have look on it

Comment: Hi, that's because you are adding the raw data and the "Items" observable array is expecting a "Contact" object, the solution is to call instead:
ContactModel.Items.push(new Contact(ContactModel.ContactData[1]))

Comment: Yes you are correct please see the updated fiddle. the problem now is when i click a add button again the then main contact highlighted multiple time http://jsfiddle.net/QmQy9/7/

Comment: It was using the Contact key to figure the one selected, i changed the comparison to use the Object, http://jsfiddle.net/QmQy9/10/.